# MySQL said: 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: mysql

Also the error message in xampp control panel states:

**Found Path**: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL
20:08:20  [mysql]

**Expected Path**: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

Can  you help as this is a fresh install of xampp v.3.2.1
I followed the instructions on install I don't know why it's not working.
Do I need to change the path in the httpd.conf file in mysql for it to find the path?

Answer (score 1):

It looks mysql is already installed in your system in the above mentioned "Found Path". If already installed mysql is not needed, uninstall it. Now try to run our new Xampp mysql server, it will run. Otherwise you can run the xampp mysql using "mysql_start" batch file which is under XAMPP folder.